# Creating addEdge method for bidrectional graph

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, graph

the requirements are:

> Using your knowledge of the Graphs data structure, complete the
> `addEdge()` method to create bidirectional edges between two vertices.
>
> Remember to verify that each argument is an instance of the `Vertex`
> class.
>
> A simple `Graph` instance, `friendNetwork`, is provided so that you can
> check the behavior of the `addEdge()` method as you implement it.

my code is

```js
const Edge = require('./Edge.js');
const Vertex = require('./Vertex.js');

class Graph {
  constructor() {
    this.vertices = [];
  }

  addVertex(data) {
    const newVertex = new Vertex(data);
    this.vertices.push(newVertex);

    return newVertex;
  }

  addEdge(vertexOne, vertexTwo) {
    if (!(vertexOne instanceof Vertex) || !(vertexTwo instanceof Vertex)) {
      throw new Error('Edge start and end must both be Vertex');
    }
    
    const newEdge = new Edge(vertexOne, vertexTwo);
    vertexOne.addEdge(newEdge);
    vertexTwo.addEdge(newEdge);
  }

  print() {
    this.vertices.forEach(vertex => vertex.print());
  }
}

const friendNetwork = new Graph();
const friendSara = friendNetwork.addVertex('Sara');
const friendMeera = friendNetwork.addVertex('Meera');
friendNetwork.addEdge(friendSara, friendMeera);
friendNetwork.print();

module.exports = Graph;
```

i keep getting error

```
/home/ccuser/workspace/assessment-aed01d489e69459a85cbdc42c2a13067/Vertex.js:13
      throw new Error('Edge start and end must both be Vertex');
      ^

Error: Edge start and end must both be Vertex
    at Vertex.addEdge (/home/ccuser/workspace/assessment-aed01d489e69459a85cbdc42c2a13067/Vertex.js:13:13)
    at Graph.addEdge (/home/ccuser/workspace/assessment-aed01d489e69459a85cbdc42c2a13067/Graph.js:22:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ccuser/workspace/assessment-aed01d489e69459a85cbdc42c2a13067/Graph.js:34:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:75:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

i tried solving add edge method and i was expecting to get error free output i also tried making class vertex instead of graph  but then my answer was rejected

Comment: Didn't you add that `throw` yourself? Have you tried printing those vertices out?

Comment: The stack trace shows that the error occurs in `Vertex.js` You didn't provide the code of that file.

Answer (score 0):

```
    const Edge = require('./Edge.js');
const Vertex = require('./Vertex.js');

class Graph {
  constructor() {
    this.vertices = [];
  }

  addVertex(data) {
    const newVertex = new Vertex(data);
    this.vertices.push(newVertex);
    return newVertex;
  }

  addEdge(vertexOne, vertexTwo) {
    if (!(vertexOne instanceof Vertex) || !(vertexTwo instanceof Vertex)) {
      throw new Error('Ambos os argumentos devem ser instâncias da classe Vertex');
    }

    vertexOne.addEdge(vertexTwo);
    vertexTwo.addEdge(vertexOne);
  }

  print() {
    this.vertices.forEach(vertex => vertex.print());
  }
}

const friendNetwork = new Graph();
const friendSara = friendNetwork.addVertex('Sara');
const friendMeera = friendNetwork.addVertex('Meera');
friendNetwork.addEdge(friendSara, friendMeera);
friendNetwork.print();

module.exports = Graph;
```